# One Page Checkout - save customer address before complete the order

Tags: onepage-checkout, address

Does someone write an observer to save the customer address before the user completes the order ? This is possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already "saved" in the `sales_flat_quote_address` table upon progression through Onepage Checkout for both guests and for registered customers.

Comment: How can I save data address from sales_flat_quote_address to customer address? There is an observer for this ?

Comment: There is standard Magento functionality to save billing or shipping address to customer address book if customer has not any address. You should check checkbox during checkout, explore standart theme of magento.

Comment: @EduardoLuz there is an observer for just about everything. The point is that it's not fully clear what your use case is or what you're going to do with it that makes it difficult for us to give you a fully-fleshed-out solution.